# Problema obtener valores por método GET

Tags: symfony3

Tengo el siguiente metodo dentro de mi controlador de `tickets`

```
/**
 * @Route("/resultado_busqueda/{ticket}",options={"expose"=true},name="resultado_busqueda"),requirements={"ticket"="\d+"})
 * @Method 'GET'
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function consulta_ticket_id($ticket = 1){

    return new Response('El id es ' . $ticket);
}
```

Este recibe los datos de una barra de busqueda;

```
<div class="barra_buqueda">
        <form action="resultado_busqueda" method="GET">
       <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar ticket" name="ticket" required>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, al pulsar intro me lleva a la url esperada `http://taskapp.xyz/app_dev.php/resultado_busqueda?ticket=12313`

el problema es que no me lee el valor de la variable `ticket` de la url ,siempre me escribe `1`que es el valor que le he colocado por defecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me he leido la [documentación](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html) para llegar hasta este punto, pero no he logrado nada

**Solución;**

Decidí hacerlo con la super global `$_GET`

Comment: si estas faciendo un formulario, se te es mas facil enviarlo por el metodo post

Comment: si, aunque también podría usar la variable super global `$_GET`. El punto es que estoy en un diplomado y estoy aprendiendo a utilizar el framework symfony3. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: si, pero para usar esa variable en el route debes colocar que estas mandando un parametro

Comment: intenta con $_GET['ticket']. si no tienes que inyectar la dependencia del request para que a partir de ahí puedas desmenuzar la solicitud.